# Error database connection is missing while using cae bake

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to bake my models, controllers and views using 'cake bake'.I entered default when it promp for database configuration. Then the command prompt displays an error message saying

```
Database connection "My sql" is missing or could not be created.
```

I have edit the path to environment variables as follow;

```
;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3;C:\wamp\www\fit or fat\lib\Cake\Console;
```

I have no idea what about what I should do.

Comment: if the error message is exactly as shown in the question: you should fix the typo in [the datasource you're trying to use](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/Config/database.php.default#L68). Please _always_ tag your question with the version you are using. Note that cli and web use different php.ini files - one can work fine while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the [CakePHP site](http://cakephp.org/) in your browser and go to Documentation / Book / Getting Started/ [CakePHP Database Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#cakephp-database-configuration). You'll find an explanation on what file you need to edit to provide your database credentials.